# What is the python function equivalent of Date() in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

Is there a function in python which is equivalent of Date() in NodeJS? Below is how the output of Node Date() looks like:

[image]

I want the exact format in Python.

Comment: you might have to manually format a little to get the ISO format used in [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct equivalent would be the datetime.now() function from datetime module.

So you would need something like:

```py
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(current_time)
```

This will print:

```
2023-04-16 10:54:12.735129
```

To bring it in the same format as the one in screenshot you can do something like:

```py
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(current_time)
```

Which will print

```
2023-04-16T10:54:12.735147
```